# invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
use qcvalues_test
go

select [finalConc]
      ,[rowid] from qvalues where rowid in (select rowid from batchinfo where instrument = 'TF1') 
and name='qc1'
and compound='etg'
group by finalConc
having COUNT(rowid)=2
```

why am i getting this error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Column 'qvalues.rowid' is invalid in
>   the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/column-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-either-an-aggr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory - you need to use an [aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258901%28SQL.80%29.aspx):

```
SELECT
    [finalConc],
    MIN([rowid]) AS minRowId,
    MAX([rowid]) AS maxRowId
FROM ...
```

Comment: +1 Given the OP's `HAVING` clause this is the only sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi herrow
To solve this problem you need to replace
select [finalConc] 
      **,[rowid]** from qvalues
with
select [finalConc] 
      ,**Count([rowid])** from qvalues