# Column "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I would like to display the column `B` in my below SQL, but when I add it to the query it gives me the following error:

> Column T2.B'
>   is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

**My code:**

```
SELECT A, COUNT(B) as T1, B 
FROM T2 
WHERE ID=1 
GROUP BY A
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group By clause causing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314836/group-by-clause-causing-error). If you searched here on your error message, you'd find lots of matches here that would have answered this for you. Please at least put the effort into doing that, as well as in actually *reading* the error message, which not only describes the exact problem but tells you exactly which column is causing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Put in other words, this error is telling you that SQL Server does not know *which* `B` to select from the group.

Either you want to select one specific value (e.g. the `MIN`, `SUM`, or `AVG`) in which case you would use the appropriate aggregate function, or you want to select every value as a new row (i.e. including `B` in the `GROUP BY` field list).

---

Consider the following data:

```
ID  A   B
1   1  13
1   1  79
1   2  13
1   2  13
1   2  42
```

The query

```
SELECT A, COUNT(B) AS T1 
FROM T2 
GROUP BY A
```

would return:

```
A  T1
1  2
2  3
```

which is all well and good.

However consider the following (illegal) query, which would produce this error:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(B) AS T1, B 
FROM T2 
GROUP BY A
```

And its returned data set illustrating the problem:

```
A  T1  B
1  2   13? 79? Both 13 and 79 as separate rows? (13+79=92)? ...?
2  3   13? 42? ...?
```

---

However, the following two queries make this clear, and will not cause the error:

1. Using an aggregate

   ```
   SELECT A, COUNT(B) AS T1, SUM(B) AS B
   FROM T2
   GROUP BY A
   ```

   would return:

   ```
   A  T1  B
   1  2   92
   2  3   68
   ```
2. Adding the column to the `GROUP BY` list

   ```
   SELECT A, COUNT(B) AS T1, B
   FROM T2
   GROUP BY A, B
   ```

   would return:

   ```
   A  T1  B
   1  1   13
   1  1   79
   2  2   13
   2  1   42
   ```

Comment: thanks for this detailed explanation - really solved some of my questions. the tricky part with the initial problem, is that you can run the query on some optimal data set, and you wont get that exception. but when you've got some duplicate data for B, you will receive that exception. So better plan your query with the examples that lc. gave upfront :)

Comment: what a nice piece of answer !!

Comment: Great answer - but I am getting the error when I have no group_by logic period

Answer (score 2):

Add column in the group by like below:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(B) as T1, B 
FROM T2 
WHERE ID=1 
GROUP BY A,B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use case in update and SWAP as many as you want

```
update Table SET column=(case when is_row_1 then value_2 else value_1 end) where rule_to_match_swap_columns
```

Answer (score 0):

The consequence of this is that you may need a rather insane-looking query, e. g.,

```
SELECT [dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[lngRecordID]            AS lngRecordID
          ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[vcrSourceWorkbookName]  AS vcrSourceWorkbookName
          ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[vcrImportFileName]      AS vcrImportFileName
          ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[dtmLastWriteTime]       AS dtmLastWriteTime
          ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[lngNRecords]            AS lngNRecords
          ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[lngSizeOnDisk]          AS lngSizeOnDisk
          ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[lngLastIdentity]        AS lngLastIdentity
          ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[dtmImportCompletedTime] AS dtmImportCompletedTime
          ,MIN ( [tblTimeRecords].[dtmActivity_Date] )              AS dtmPeriodFirstWorkDate
          ,MAX ( [tblTimeRecords].[dtmActivity_Date] )              AS dtmPeriodLastWorkDate
          ,SUM ( [tblTimeRecords].[decMan_Hours_Actual] )           AS decHoursWorked
          ,SUM ( [tblTimeRecords].[decAdjusted_Hours] )             AS decHoursBilled
      FROM [dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles]
      LEFT JOIN   [dbo].[tblTimeRecords]
              ON  [dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[lngRecordID] = [dbo].[tblTimeRecords].[lngTimeSheetExportFile]
        GROUP BY  [dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[lngRecordID]
                 ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[vcrSourceWorkbookName]
                 ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[vcrImportFileName]
                 ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[dtmLastWriteTime]
                 ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[lngNRecords]
                 ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[lngSizeOnDisk]
                 ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[lngLastIdentity]
                 ,[dbo].[tblTimeSheetExportFiles].[dtmImportCompletedTime]
```

Since the primary table is a summary table, its primary key handles the only grouping or ordering that is truly necessary. Hence, the GROUP BY clause exists solely to satisfy the query parser.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by adding the each group by clause which is mentioned in the error when we execute the query.

For eg: let error shows message as--

```
Column 'table.dealer' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Then I have added table.dealer column in the 'group by' clause as:

```
Group by table.dealer
```

Its solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the field values using groupBy then you can use this code in sequelize:`Table.count( { attributes: ['column'],  group: 'column', }` 
This will resolve this error Column "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"