# SQL Server : Group by breaks my program

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have the following query. The idea is to inner join the records and group them in order to get one record (the latest one) from each group.

- If I add the `GROUP BY` (like on the example bellow) it doesn't work.
- If I remove the `GROUP BY` the query works but display duplicated data.
- If I group by all fields that I selected before the inner join, it works but not as intended. It will display all records.

Any suggestions?

```
 SELECT 
    Calibrations.Cert_No, 
    Calibrations.Cust_Ref, 
    Calibrations.Rec_Date, 
    Instruments.Inst_ID, 
    Instruments.Description, 
    Instruments.Model_no, 
    Instruments.Manufacturer, 
    Instruments.Serial_no, 
    Instruments.Status, 
    Instruments.Cust_Acc_No  
 FROM 
    Instruments 
 INNER JOIN 
    Calibrations ON Instruments.Inst_ID = Calibrations.Inst_ID  
 WHERE 
    Instruments.Cust_Name = '" & Session("MM_Username") & "' 
    AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" & Session("MM_Password") & "' 
    AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" & Replace(rsDue__MMColParam, "'", "''") & "' 
    AND Instruments.Status IN ('N')
 GROUP BY
    Instruments.Inst_ID  
 ORDER BY 
    Calibrations.Rec_Date DESC
```

Comment: Actually, this is a [sql-server] duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/what-does-the-invalid-not-contained-in-either-an-aggregate-function-message-m

Comment: When you say, "It doesn't work", what error is it throwing you *exactly*.  Copy/paste the above into SQL Server and substitute the variables with real values and see what SQL Server is telling you.  It usually gives you a good idea of why it doesn't like a particular piece of code.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://calibrations.inlec.uk/db-error.png).                     ![Valid XHTML](http://calibrations.inlec.uk/db-error2.png).                           ![Valid XHTML](http://calibrations.inlec.uk/db-error3.png).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have columns in the `SELECT` part of your query, that does not appear in the `GROUP BY` part of the query, unless they are inside an aggregate function such as MIN(), MAX(), SUM(), etc...

Think about it this way: Say you have a table that looks like this:

```
+----------+------+--------+
|   Col1   | Col2 | NumCol |
+----------+------+--------+
| Value 1a | ABC  |    123 |
| Value 1a | DEF  |    234 |
| Value 1b | GHI  |    345 |
| Value 1b | JKL  |    456 |
+----------+------+--------+
```

This query would **not** work:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, NumCol FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY NumCol
```

Why? Because you are only grouping by `Col1`, and since this column only contains two distinct values, the query engine doesn't know which of the values it should display in the `Col2` or `NumCol` columns (since these contain 4 distinct values).

To fix this, you should either remove the columns from your `SELECT` statement like this:

```
SELECT Col1 FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1
```

...or aggregate the columns somehow. For example like this:

```
SELECT Col1, MAX(Col2) AS Col2, SUM(NumCol) AS NumCol FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY NumCol
```

However, this is not the same as getting the "latest record", or for example the record with the largest `NumCol` for each distinct value of `Col1`. To do that, you should consider using the ROW_NUMBER() windowed function like this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, NumCol FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY NumCol DESC) AS N
    FROM Table
) AS T
WHERE T.N = 1
```

How this works is a topic of its own, but basically, ROW_NUMBER assigns a running value to each row, resetting the value each time it encounters a new value in `Col1`. The ordering makes sure that the running value starts with 1 for the record that has the largest `NumCol` value. In the outer select statement, you then apply a filter on this running value, to get only the first record for each distinct `Col1` value - that is the record with the largets `NumCol` value.

Comment: Hi Dan, I tryed a few different ways and still breaks it. I am quite new to MsSQL and this is driving me crazy as it's the only point that needs sorting in the application.

Comment: Hi Dan, tryed like this but no luck! can you see the error?

Comment: SELECT Calibrations.Cust_Ref, Calibrations.Rec_Date, Instruments.Inst_ID, Instruments.Description, Instruments.Model_no, Instruments.Manufacturer, Instruments.Serial_no, Instruments.Status, Instruments.Cust_Acc_No FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Instruments.Inst_ID ORDER BY Instruments.Inst_ID DESC) AS N FROM Instruments) AS T WHERE T.N = 1;"

Comment: Put your entire original query into the inner select statement, and then add the ROW_NUMBER-function to the list of columns in the `SELECT` part of the inner query. Then wrap the whole thing in an outer select statement. Something like this: `SELECT * FROM (<<original_query_with_row_number>>) AS T WHERE T.N = 1`

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Calibrations.Cust_Ref, Calibrations.Rec_Date, Instruments.Inst_ID, Instruments.Description, Instruments.Model_no, Instruments.Manufacturer, Instruments.Serial_no, Instruments.Status, Instruments.Cust_Acc_No  FROM Instruments INNER JOIN Calibrations ON Instruments.Inst_ID = Calibrations.Inst_ID  WHERE Instruments.Cust_Name = '" & Session("MM_Username") & "' AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" & Session("MM_Password") & "' AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" + Replace(rsAll__MMColParam, "'", "''") + "' AND Instruments.Status IN ('A')) AS T WHERE T.N = 1;"

Comment: Almost. You forgot the windowing function on the ROW_NUMBER. Change the first part of your query to this: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Instruments.Inst_ID ORDER BY Calibrations.Rec_Date DESC) AS N, Calibrations.Cust_Ref, Calibrations.Rec_Date ...`

Comment: Returns : Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ROW_NUMBER('1') Calibrations.Cust_Ref'

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Instruments.Inst_ID ORDER BY Calibrations.Rec_Date DESC) AS N, Calibrations.Cust_Ref, Calibrations.Rec_Date, Instruments.Inst_ID, Instruments.Description, Instruments.Model_no, Instruments.Manufacturer, Instruments.Serial_no, Instruments.Status, Instruments.Cust_Acc_No  FROM Instruments INNER JOIN Calibrations ON Instruments.Inst_ID = Calibrations.Inst_ID  WHERE Instruments.Cust_Name = '" & Session("MM_Username") & "' AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '" & Session("MM_Password") & "' AND Instruments.Cust_Acc_No = '"

Comment: + Replace(rsAll__MMColParam, "'", "''") + "' AND Instruments.Status IN ('A') AS T WHERE T.N = 1;"

Comment: I'm sorry. It seems Access does not understand the ROW_NUMBER-syntax. This query works fine in SQL Server Management Studio, however. Maybe you can somehow mark this as a pass-through query?

Answer (score 1):

When you are [grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) in a SQL query, you have to either list the column in the group by clause or use an aggregate function -> There can not be columns without aggregation since they are not in the group by list.

You did not provided any information about your specific goal, but either you can get the values by aggregating (using `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, etc) functions to get the desired data, or you can use `subqueries` to retrieve the distinct list than another one to retrieve their specific data, or you can use `analytic functions` (FIRST_VALUE, LAST_VALUE, etc) and distinct.

Comment: Hi Pred, thanks for your comment, I will have a look and try to solve the issue.

Comment: SELECT Calibrations.Cust_Ref, Calibrations.Rec_Date, Instruments.Inst_ID, Instruments.Description, Instruments.Model_no, Instruments.Manufacturer, Instruments.Serial_no, Instruments.Status, Instruments.Cust_Acc_No FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Instruments.Inst_ID ORDER BY Instruments.Inst_ID DESC) AS N FROM Instruments) AS T WHERE T.N = 1;"

Comment: Seems legit if it retrieves the data what you are expected. Do not forget, that we do not have the database and we can not read your mind :)