# Column is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT * 
FROM Book b 
WHERE b.book_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT( c.book_id ) 
                    FROM Copy c 
                    WHERE c.copy_id IN (SELECT copy_id 
                                        FROM Loan 
                                        WHERE Datediff(DAY, Getdate() - 180, loan_date) > 180) 
                    GROUP  BY c.copy_id 
                    HAVING Count(copy_id) > 10)
```

When I ran this query I'm getting below error.

> "Column 'Copy.Book_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "invalid, not contained in either an aggregate function" message mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/what-does-the-invalid-not-contained-in-either-an-aggregate-function-message-m)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to have a field after `select` in a `select` statement with `group by` part you should add its name after `group by` too and don't use `distinct` keyword, I think you need a code like this:

```
SELECT c.book_id  
FROM   Copy c 
WHERE  c.copy_id IN (SELECT copy_id 
                 FROM   Loan 
                 WHERE  Datediff(DAY, Getdate() - 180, loan_date) > 180) 
GROUP  BY c.book_id
HAVING Count(copy_id) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by `c.copy_id`, yet, you want to select `c.book_id`. This is invalid. You might consider one option from the following:

- `group by` `c.book_id`
- `group by` `c.book_id` besides `c.copy_id`
- don't use `group by` in the inner query
- `select` `c.copy_id` and use it in the outer select as well

I believe the very first option makes the most sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem causing the error is that you're grouping on the wrong column in the subquery, it should be `b.book_id`.

Then I think you're datediff comparison might have the dates in the wrong order (but that depends on your intent and I might have misunderstood what you're trying to do).

So with the changes maybe this query might be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM Book b 
WHERE b.Book_Id IN (
    SELECT c.Book_id
    FROM Copy c 
    JOIN Loan l ON c.copy_id = l.copy_id
    WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, Loan_date, getdate()-180) > 180
    GROUP BY c.Book_Id 
    HAVING COUNT(l.Copy_Id) > 10
)
```