# Problems selecting columns with aggregates (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm seriously stuck. Please bear with me though because I'm new to databases.:)

Anyway, I need to display the `StudentID`, the subject where the student has the highest grade in, and the grade of that subject.

Here's the code I have:

```
SELECT 
    Grades.Student_ID,
    Subject.Subject_Code,
    MAX(Grades.Grade)
FROM 
    Grades
LEFT JOIN 
    Subject ON Grades.Subject_ID = Subject.Subject_ID
GROUP BY 
    Grades.Student_ID
```

But it has this error:

> 'Subject.Subject_Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

But I can't include `Subject_Code` in `GROUP BY` because the results will be different.

What can I do to only show the

```
Student_ID || (subject with highest grade) || (grade of that subject)
```

How can I work around this error?

Comment: you need to `group by grades.student_id, subject.subject_code` to get rid of that error. also, are you SURE you're using mysql? by default mysql allows your query without that error

Comment: My mistake. Its SQL Server

Comment: I mentioned that I made a mistake. Its SQL Server, not MySql. Sorry for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "invalid, not contained in either an aggregate function" message mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/what-does-the-invalid-not-contained-in-either-an-aggregate-function-message-m)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a group wise maximum. Here's one approach joining back to a derived table containing the top grade for each student (This approach should work on most RDBMS, including MySql):

```
SELECT X.Student_ID,
    s.Subject_Code,
    x.TopGrade
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    Grades.Student_ID,
    MAX(Grades.Grade) AS TopGrade
  FROM Grades
  GROUP BY Grades.Student_ID
) x
INNER JOIN Grades g
ON g.Student_ID = x.Student_ID AND g.Grade = x.TopGrade
LEFT JOIN Subject s
      ON g.Subject_ID = s.Subject_ID
```

If the same student has two or more marks with exactly the same grade, it will return all Subjects.

Here's my original answer, which will work on SQL Server

```
SELECT x.Student_ID, x.Subject_Code, x.Grade
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    Grades.Student_ID,
    Subject.Subject_Code,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Grades.Student_ID ORDER BY Grades.Grade DESC) AS [Rank],
    Grades.Grade
  FROM Grades
  LEFT JOIN Subject
      ON Grades.Subject_ID = Subject.Subject_ID
) x
WHERE x.[Rank] = 1;
```

[SqlFiddle of both the above queries here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8a42/6). In addition, there is an example with ROW_NUMBER with an additional arbitrary `ORDER BY` to pick one top subject when the student has equal marks in two or more subjects.

Comment: Thanks it works! But how can I exclude Rank from showing in the results? Changing * to specific columns doesnt work.

Comment: I've updated `SELECT x.Student_ID, x.Subject_Code, x.Grade` - the trick is that we've aliased the derived table as 'x', so the original table names are lost - this is most likely where things went wrong.

Comment: +1 - Though I do have one recommendation.  Only include `Grades` in the inline view (Or use a CTE) and call it `RankedGrades`.  Then join `Subject` outside rather than inside the inline view or CTE.  This is mainly a readability / maintainability change (encapsulating minimal behaviour, decoupling the Subject lookup from the Ranking), but in other more complex scenarios it can have performance benefits too.