# SQL INNER JOIN - Column name in join is also in select *error*

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I'm still pretty new to SQL and am having issues. I am using a variation of the classic Northwind Database. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

**Here is the problem:**

```
/*
Join Products and ProductVendors to display by product, the product
number, the average wholesale price, and the average retail price.
*/
```

**Here's what I've got:**

```
SELECT Products.productNumber As [Product Number],
       CAST(AVG(wholesalePrice) as decimal (8,2)) As [Average Wholesale Price],
       CAST(AVG(retailPrice) as decimal (8,2))  As [Average Retail Price]
FROM Products INNER JOIN ProductVendors 
       ON Products.productNumber = ProductVendors.productNumber
```

**Here's the error I get:**

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>       Column 'Products.productNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: is it MySQL or MS SQL server?

Comment: use:.... group by Products.productNumber, wholesalePrice,retailPrice

Comment: definitely not mysql - it couldnt care less if all the select fields are in the `group by`

Comment: the error explains it all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "invalid, not contained in either an aggregate function" message mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/what-does-the-invalid-not-contained-in-either-an-aggregate-function-message-m)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exception text is self-explanatory. Since you're using aggregate functions (`avg` in your case) you have to group by `Products.productNumber` too.

```
select Products.productNumber aa [Product Number],
       CAST(AVG(wholesalePrice) as decimal (8,2)) as [Average Wholesale Price],
       CAST(AVG(retailPrice) as decimal (8,2))  as [Average Retail Price]
from Products inner join ProductVendors 
    on Products.productNumber = ProductVendors.productNumber
group by Products.productNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use aggregation functions, you must have a `group by` statement.

```
SELECT Products.productNumber As [Product Number],
       CAST(AVG(wholesalePrice) as decimal (8,2)) As [Average Wholesale Price],
       CAST(AVG(retailPrice) as decimal (8,2))  As [Average Retail Price]
FROM Products INNER JOIN ProductVendors ON Products.productNumber = ProductVendors.productNumber
group by Products.productNumber
```

An the `group by` statement must contain all columns wich are not in a aggregation function

Answer (score 0):

If you use `AGGREGATE` functions then `GROUP BY` clause must be specified.

```
SELECT Products.productNumber As [Product Number],
       CAST(AVG(wholesalePrice) as decimal (8,2)) As [Average Wholesale Price],
       CAST(AVG(retailPrice) as decimal (8,2))  As [Average Retail Price]
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN ProductVendors ON Products.productNumber = ProductVendors.productNumber
GROUP BY Products.productNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `AGGREGATE` functions then `GROUP BY` clause must be specified, here you are selecting `ProductNumber` so specify `GROUP BY` clause on that

```
SELECT Products.productNumber As [Product Number],
       CAST(AVG(wholesalePrice) as decimal (8,2)) As [Average Wholesale Price],
       CAST(AVG(retailPrice) as decimal (8,2))  As [Average Retail Price]
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN ProductVendors ON Products.productNumber = ProductVendors.productNumber
GROUP BY Products.productNumber
```