# Column 'columnName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have two database tables, `project` and `story`. The one project having different types of story. I wanted to display all project with each type story count.

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT
     p.id,
     p.proj_id,
     p.proj_title,
     p.proj_status,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN s.story_type = 'TY_FEATURES' THEN 1 END) AS FEATURES,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN s.story_type = 'TY_ENHANCEMENTS' THEN 1 END) AS ENHANCEMENTS,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN s.story_type = 'TY_DEPENDENCIES' THEN 1 END) AS DEPENDENCIES,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN s.story_type = 'TY_ADHOC' THEN 1 END) AS ADHOC,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN s.story_type = 'TY_DEMO' THEN 1 END) AS DEMO,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN s.story_type = 'TY_IMPROVEMENTS' THEN 1 END) AS IMPROVEMENTS
FROM
     project p LEFT JOIN story s
ON
     p.proj_id = s.proj_id
GROUP BY
     p.id,
     p.proj_id,
     p.proj_status,
     p.proj_title
```

The SQL Query working fine, but I wanted to display all column from `project` table. If the column added in `SELECT` like `p.newExistingInTable`. I need to add in  `GROUP BY` too, how can I make flexible? or any alternative optimized SQL query?

Error showing if new column added only in `SELECT`:

> Column 'project.newExistingInTable' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I can't see `newExistingInTable` in your query - can you edit to the form that produces the error you specify?

Comment: It should be also need group by this column "story_type"

Comment: try [searching the site for that error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+is+invalid+in+the+select+list+because+it+is+not+contained+in+either+an+aggregate+function+or+the+GROUP+BY+clause) and you'll see dozons of answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/column-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-either-an-aggr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the story summaries inside a subquery:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.proj_id,
    p.proj_title,
    p.proj_status,
    FEATURES,
    ENHANCEMENTS,
    DEPENDENCIES,
    ADHOC,
    DEMO,
    IMPROVEMENTS
FROM
    project p LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT proj_id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN story_type = 'TY_FEATURES' THEN 1 END) AS FEATURES,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN story_type = 'TY_ENHANCEMENTS' THEN 1 END) AS ENHANCEMENTS,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN story_type = 'TY_DEPENDENCIES' THEN 1 END) AS DEPENDENCIES,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN story_type = 'TY_ADHOC' THEN 1 END) AS ADHOC,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN story_type = 'TY_DEMO' THEN 1 END) AS DEMO,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN story_type = 'TY_IMPROVEMENTS' THEN 1 END) AS IMPROVEMENTS
   FROM story
   GROUP BY proj_id) s
        ON
             p.proj_id = s.proj_id
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use individual  subqueries for each count:

```
SELECT id,proj_id, proj_title,proj_status,
   -- any other columns from project ...
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM story s 
    WHERE s.story_type='TY_FEATURES'  
    AND s.proj_id=p.proj_id) FEATURES,
   (SELECT ... other story counts ) colname
 FROM project p
```

That way no `JOIN` to story is necessary and you don't need `group by` either. But of course you need to link each subquery properly to the main record by two `where` conditions.

Comment: It's working, but writing subqueries for each count, it's not looking good for performance perspective.

Comment: Fair enough. The performance depends of course on the number of 'count' columns you will need. On MS-SQL server I have similar queries in production and the performance compares well to the `CASE/GROUP BY` solution (I tested them both there).

Comment: Thanks, I will consider your suggestions and experience in my work. thank you so much.

Comment: I would be interested in the reasons for the downvotes. Subqueries always come at a cost. Whether the performance is going to be worse depends on the number of these subqueries compared to the total number of records the `case/inner join/group by` would have to plough through.