# Column 'personal.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that this problem is already very well covered, but nonetheless, I can not solve it unfortunately.

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Column
>   'personal.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The problem disappears if you remove the first one "group by p"

```
@Query(value = "select p from Inspection i left join i.cohort c left join i.personal p left join fetch p.personal ip left join fetch ip.transfer t left join fetch t.profession left join fetch t.department left join fetch p.outsidePersonal op left join fetch op.organisation where (:personalType is null or p.type = :personalType) and (:department is null or t.department=:department) and (:organisation is null or op.organisation=:organisation) and (:unit is null or i.unit = :unit) and (:dateFrom is null or i.date>=:dateFrom) and (:dateTo is null or i.date<=:dateTo) and (:controlType is null or c.parent=:controlType) and (:measureType is null or i.cohort=:measureType) group by p", 
countQuery = "select count(p) from Inspection i left join i.cohort c left join i.personal p left join p.personal ip left join ip.transfer t left join p.outsidePersonal op where (:personalType is null or p.type = :personalType) and (:department is null or t.department=:department) and (:organisation is null or op.organisation=:organisation) and (:unit is null or i.unit = :unit) and (:dateFrom is null or i.date>=:dateFrom) and (:dateTo is null or i.date<=:dateTo) and (:controlType is null or c.parent=:controlType) and (:measureType is null or i.cohort=:measureType) group by p")
```

Comment: The error message says it pretty clear! You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/column-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-either-an-aggr)

Comment: When using the database in memory everything works without problems. How can this be explained? How correctly to correct such error?