# Sequelize group by include model works correct in MySQL, but get "column ... is invalid in select list..." error in SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

Sequelize group by include models work correct in MySQL, but not in SQL Server, core codes are as following

Models

```
var topics = sequelize.define('topics', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        title:{
            type:  DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
});
var comment = sequelize.define('comment', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        text: { type:DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull:false },
        topic_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull:false }
});

// Association
comment.hasOne(topics, {foreignKey:"id", sourceKey:"topic_id"})
topics.hasMany(comment, { foreignKey:"topic_id", sourceKey:"id" })

// Query get error in SQL Server, but goes well in MySQL
topics.findAll({
        group:["topics.id"],
        include: [{ model:comment, attributes:[] }]
})
```

Above code runs well in mySQL, but when runs in SQL Server, I get error "Column 'topics.id' is invalid in the selected list...."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/sql-server-column-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e

Comment: @RohitDalal, thanks for your reply, but I rarely know SQL, my problem is the query can't operate group action in SQL,  like this:  topics.findAll({
        group:["topics.id"],
        include: [{ model:comment, attributes:[] }]
}), if I remove group by , it goes well

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem, in MSSQL, the trick is you need to list all fields in the group, like following:

```
topics.findAll({
   group:["topics.id","topics.title"], // <---- need to list "topics.title"
   include: [{ model:comment, attributes:[] }],
   attributes:{
      include:[[sequelize.fn('count',sequelize.col('comments.id')),'participants']]
   }
})
```