# Column 'Buy.title' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

When executing this SQL I get the error :

> Column 'Buy.title' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

SQL:

```
IF(@sal IS NOT NULL AND @title IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT title,type1, SUM(tedat) 
    FROM Buy
    WHERE(@sal = YEAR(tarikh) AND @title = title)       
END
```

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags.

Comment: Its also useful to put a body of text in the question too and not just let the title speak for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server - Column "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/sql-server-column-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Comment: Your `if` is redundant.  The query returns no rows if either parameters are `NULL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to group by the columns on the result set that are not within aggregate functions, so it will apply the aggregate function (sum) on groups of records with those same title and type.

Documentation : [SQL Server GROUP BY clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
IF(@sal IS NOT NULL AND @title IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT title,type1, SUM(tedat) 
    FROM Buy
    WHERE(@sal = YEAR(tarikh) AND @title = title)
    GROUP BY title, type1
END
```