# SQL Server INNER JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

In sql server I'm trying to group by each sales people some infos as follow:

I have 2 tables: Positions and Clients

In Positions table, I have the following columns: Client_Id, Balance, Acquisition_Cost and in the Clients table I use the following columns: Client_Id and Sales_person.

I want to group by Sales_person (Clients table) the Client_id, Balance, Acquisition_Cost (Positions table)

I tried this:

```
SELECT Positions.Client_ID, Positions.Balance, Positions.Acquisition_cost
FROM Positions
INNER JOIN Clients ON Positions.Client_ID = Clients.Client_ID
GROUP BY Sales_person
```

It gives me "Positions.Client_ID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause".

I precise I'm pretty new on SQL so that does not ring that much a bell to me.

Comment: Perhaps you simply want `ORDER BY Sales_person`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/column-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-either-an-aggr)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you guys, here's the code that works for me in this case:

````
SELECT Positions.Client_Id, Clients.Sales_person, SUM(Positions.Balance) as sum_balance_impacted, SUM(Positions.Acquisition_cost) as sum_acquisition_cost 
FROM Positions 
INNER JOIN Clients ON Positions.Client_Id= Clients.Client_Id
GROUP BY Clients.Sales_person, Positions.Client_Id```
````

Answer (score 0):

For any column in your `SELECT` that you aren't including in the `GROUP BY`, you need to use some kind of aggregate function (`MAX`, `SUM`, etc.) on the column. So you could write it like this:

```
SELECT Positions.Client_ID
     , Clients.Sales_person
     , SUM(Positions.Balance) Balance_Sum,
     , SUM(Positions.Acquisition_cost) Acquisition_Cost_Sum
  FROM Positions
INNER JOIN Clients ON Positions.Client_ID = Clients.Client_ID
GROUP BY Positions.Client_ID
       , Clients.Sales_person
```

If you only want the totals by Sales_person and not client_ID, you could just remove client_id from the `SELECT` AND `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Clients.Sales_person
     , SUM(Positions.Balance) Balance_Sum,
     , SUM(Positions.Acquisition_cost) Acquisition_Cost_Sum
  FROM Positions
INNER JOIN Clients ON Positions.Client_ID = Clients.Client_ID
GROUP BY Clients.Sales_person
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Positions.Client_ID in the GROUP BY Clause, since the select expects this column if you really do not want Positions.Client_ID in the select, then no need to add in the GROUP BY Clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Client_ID, b.Sales_person, SUM(a.Balance) as Balance_Sum,SUM(a.Acquisition_cost) as Acquisition_Cost_Sum FROM Positions as a INNER JOIN Clients as b ON a.Client_ID = b.Client_ID GROUP BY a.Client_ID, b.Sales_person
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.