# Column 'Tabel1.Nama' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Column 'Tabel1.Nama' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I have two tables, table 1

[image: Table1]

and table 2

[image: Table2]

I am trying to show like this

[image: show]

my Query:

```
SELECT Tabel1.NIK, Tabel1.Nama, AVG(Table2.Nilai) AS RataRata FROM 
Tabel1, Table2 WHERE Tabel1.NIK = Table2.NIK GROUP BY Tabel1.NIK
```

but I have an error like this
Column 'Tabel1.Nama' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

anyone can fix my Query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258704/column-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-either-an-aggr)

Comment: `"i have table Table1"` THESE ARE NOT TABLES BUT IMAGES. Hi, If you need help regarding tables then please provide queries to CREATE the tables and insert sample data. In addition please provide the expected result SET according to the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Nama to the group by

```
SELECT Tabel1.NIK, Tabel1.Nama, AVG(Table2.Nilai) AS RataRata FROM Tabel1, Table2 WHERE Tabel1.NIK = Table2.NIK GROUP BY Tabel1.NIK, Tabel1.Nama
```

Or remove Nama from the select

```
SELECT Tabel1.NIK, AVG(Table2.Nilai) AS RataRata FROM Tabel1, Table2 WHERE Tabel1.NIK = Table2.NIK GROUP BY Tabel1.NIK
```

Comment: a new error appears in the first solution. like "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."

Comment: thanks for your answer, i change data type from text to char. thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide your DDL and some data sampling so that we can run the queries

Comment: Ok - you can use nvarchar instead